# How to limit the choice related to FK in DRF backend/admin panel

Tags: django-rest-framework, limit-choices-to

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="",blank=False)
    questions_count = models.IntegerField(default="")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000,default="",blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True,blank=False)
    roll_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="",related_name='quiz')
    label = models.CharField(max_length=2000,default="")
    order = models.IntegerField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label



class Answer(models.Model):
    question =models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    correct = models.BooleanField(default="")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000,default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


class QuizTaker(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    score = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



class Response(models.Model):
    quiztaker = models.ForeignKey(QuizTaker, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.label
```

These are my models, I have been following a tutorial on yt by Jay Coding.
I want to limit the answer choice in response model related to question in admin panel/ model so that there is choice of answer related to particular question.

Comment: it should not be possible without making custom template for admin because the answers should be filtered after question is selected i.e. on front end using java script.

Comment: also check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates